# How to display multiple result in JavaScript?

Tags: php, javascript

I want to display multiple results of multiple selected options, here I am displaying my PHP and JavaScript code.

```
function save() {
    if (!validateSave())
        return;
    var e;
    var result;
    e = document.getElementsByName("q1[]");
    for (var j = 0; j <= e.length - 1; j++) {
        if (e[j].checked) {
            result = "1:" + e[j].value;
            //break;
        }
}
```

HTML code

```
 <div class="qright">
        <!-- multioption handler --------------------------------------------------->
        <input type="hidden" name="multioption" value="true"  />
                    <!-- end ------------------------------------------------------------------->
        <label for="q1"><input type="checkbox" name="q1[]" value="1" class="styled" />Reducing cost</label>
        <label for="q1"><input type="checkbox" name="q1[]" value="2" class="styled" />Upgrading your hardware and software infrastructure</label>
        <label for="q1"><input type="checkbox" name="q1[]" value="3" class="styled" />Aligning the IT goals with the overall business strategy</label>
        <label for="q1"><input type="checkbox" name="q1[]" value="4" class="styled" />Enabling agile working</label>
        <label for="q1"><input type="checkbox" name="q1[]" value="5" class="styled" />Streamlining supplier management</label>
        <label for="q1"><input type="checkbox" name="q1[]" value="6" class="styled" />Improving network availability/access</label>
        <label for="q1"><input type="checkbox" name="q1[]" value="7"class="styled"  />Improving the utilisation of your network</label>
    </div>
```

if I select multiple options then it also display only one value, what i should change in JavaScript function?

Comment: I want to save this result in cookie

Comment: Nice edit, I know it wasn't constructive but my comment makes no sense now :(.

Comment: @MarkWalters But we know what you are about :D +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace `document.getElementsByName("q1[]");` with `document.getElementsByName("q1");`

Comment: The name of the element he's getting is literally `q1[]`

Comment: `<input type="checkbox" name="q1[]"` not the best name i've ever seen, but this is not the issue.

Comment: Dear When I replace document.getElementsByName("q1[]"); with  document.getElementsByName("q1"); the result show undefined

Answer (score 0):

```
result = "1:" + e[j].value;
```

This looks like you initialize the result every time you find a match.
(i.e. you delete the previous find and overwrite it with a new one)

You should use

```
result += j+":" +e[j].value;
```

although i do not see how this can be a good way to store multiple elements of data.

perhaps you should use an array?

```
result.push(e[j].value);
```

(in the array case you need to initialize the result var as an array `var result = new Array;`